# C# XMPP library and examples that can do secure XMPP over HTTP

Tags: c#, http, xmpp

We currently using OpenFire as our XMPP server and using SoapBox C# library to implement XMPP client.  But now we want to move to secure XMPP over HTTP (BOSH) so users can instant chat on different network.  I've search for days but could not find any C# examples to implement XMPP over HTTP.  Our application is in C# and so I need to find a C# or .NET solution, ideally keep SoapBox if possible.  Anyone has any examples or pointers to share?

Comment: I'll be interested to see if you find a solution here.  This won't be easy to accomplish.  You will probably have to go with some sort of long-polling option I would think.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an HTTPS URL for polling from any library that supports BOSH.  Although why you'd use BOSH from a real programming language other than to cut through a particularly virulent firewall, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

SoapBox mentions that "SoapBox Server,BOSH implementation works well with JSJaC, the most popular XMPP BOSH JavaScript library" on their [official website](http://www.coversant.com/Product/Studio-Overview.aspx). Even though, they didn't mention anything about BOSH implementation using SoapBox library.

But, MatriX C# library supports http-bind(bosh) implementation. [MatriX](http://www.ag-software.de/matrix-xmpp-sdk/) is a SDK/library for XMPP, written in managed C# dedicated to .NET and Silverlight technologies. But, MatriX is a commercial one.

I'm also looking the sample source for http-bind(bosh) implementation using SoapBox C# library. If anyone found please, share the link in here.